# Some Javascript is not working until hitting F12 in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

The Javascript code is working correctly in Firefox and Chrome, but for IE(I am using 11),it's not working until I hit F12 for debugging. And there is also no error displayed in debugger in IE. Any idea why?

The first function is to check if the browser support classList or not, apparently, IE doesn't support it. Here is the code:

```
function checkClassListSupport() {
    var supportsClassList = ({}).toString.call(document.body.classList) == "[object DOMTokenList]";
    return supportsClassList;
}
```

Comment: cause its Internet Explorer?

Comment: Please show the code that is not working.

Comment: You're running the page in IE9 mode or older, and the code contains references to the console. Remove the references or change the document mode to "Edge". And IE has supported `classList` since version 10.

Comment: @Teemu You are right, after I removed those console.log code, it's working now!  Can you please explain what do u mean IE9 mode? Thanks.

Comment: Open the Dev Tools, and take a look at near the top-right corner of the Dev Tools window. There's a drop-down box, select "11" (or perhaps "Edge") from the box, that way you'll run IE as IE11, not 9 or even something older.

Comment: @Teemu found it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working now if I remove the console.log code, or change the document module to "Edge".