# using reactjs on ie11, blank page on production but if the inspector is open then the page load fine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

I just create a web app using reactjs.

works fine in almost all the browsers but i need to make it work in ie11. i add the polyfills as i see on other posts and works fine if a make a npm start (you know, development version).

the issue are when i create te build version (npm run build) and then call serve -s build to load the production version of the site.

**Here is the issue i'm facing.** When i open the site on ie11 production (serve -s build) shows blank but when i open the inspector to try to see what's happening, nothing shows. then i reload the page and load perfectly.

i try to refresh the site with the inspector close but nothing happens. i have no idea to find a bug that is not showing when i open the inspector.

i need help of this great community. Anyone knows why the site loads fine if the inspector is open? do the ie11 something different when the inspector is open than the inspector close.

any idea on how to find this bug that i can't track...

Comment: Duplicate, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53631949/why-ie-11-display-blank-page-rendering-react-app

Comment: thanks @Tx_monster but is not exactly the same. i mean, i follow that post to fix it on development. but my question is about the ie11 and why works fine with the inspector open...

Comment: Have you tried to reset ie to default settings? Make sure that any extension is enabled.

Comment: Please try to check if there's any debugging code in your app. Have you ever used any `console.log()` or `console` in your code? It will break the script code and please remove this kind of code and try again. For more detailed information, you could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742781/why-does-javascript-only-work-after-opening-developer-tools-in-ie-once) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653611/some-javascript-is-not-working-until-hitting-f12-in-ie-11).